# CRI-O Pulling Image From AWS ECR: Failed to pull image, authentication required

Tags: amazon-web-services, redhat, kubernetes

Unable to pull an image from AWS ECR with the following error from Kubernetes using CRI-O as Container Runtime Interface.

`Failed to pull image "<aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region-name>.amazonaws.com/<image>": reading manifest <version> in <aws_account_id>.dkr.ecr.<region-name>.amazonaws.com/<image>: authentication required`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to install Skopeo and run the following command. Make sure to replace the region with the region your ECR image is stored in.

`skopeo login -u AWS -p $(/usr/local/bin/aws ecr get-login-password --region <AWS Region>) $(/usr/local/bin/aws sts get-caller-identity --query Account --output text).dkr.ecr.<AWS Region>.amazonaws.com`

I recommend turning this into a CRON Job and having it run every 11 hours since the tokens expire after 12 hours.